# Why i am not getting all cellForRowAtindexPath textfield values in button action while parsing in swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, button, textfield

in cellForRowAtindexPath i am getting all `alertParam, alertMinL` values means if there is one alertParam then i am getting one alertParam and if there are three alertParam then i am getting alertParam values and even in tableview but while i am validating in button then i am not getting all three values i am getting only one alertParam and min, max values why? how can i validate all three textfields in tableview?

declared in class:

```
var alertMinL: Int?
var alertMaxL: Int?
var alertParam: String?
```

code in cellForRowAt indexPath: here i am getting all values according to Json:

```
 if let customerDetail = selectedBiller?.bcustomerparms[indexPath.row] {
            alertParam = customerDetail.paramName
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = alertParam
            print("cell param values \(alertParam)")
            if var priceOfProduct: String = customerDetail.minLength {
                alertMinL = Int(priceOfProduct)
                print("cell minLen values \(alertMinL)")
            }
            if var priceOfProduct: String = customerDetail.maxLength {
                alertMaxL = Int(priceOfProduct)
            }
            cell?.searchTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchPhoneEditingChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        }
```

in buttonaction i am getting only one value even if there are tree `paramName`. how to validate all three textfields here.

```
 @objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

if self.finalSearchValue.isEmpty{
    AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter \(self.alertParam ?? "")", in: self)
}
else if self.textCount ?? 0 < self.alertMinL ?? 0{
    AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "\(self.alertParam ?? "") Not Less Than \(self.alertMinL ?? 0)", in: self)
}
else if self.textCount ?? 0 > self.alertMaxL ?? 0{
    AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "\(self.alertParam ?? "") Not More Than \(self.alertMaxL ?? 0)", in: self)
}
else if self.finalSearchValueAmnt.isEmpty && hasFinalSearchValueAmnt{
    AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter Amount", in: self)
}
else{
    billerFetchService()
}
}
```

here finalSearchValue is:

```
@objc func searchPhoneEditingChanged(textField: UITextField) {
    finalSearchValue = textField.text!
    self.textCount = self.finalSearchValue.count
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are expecting to get more than one `AlertFun.ShowAlert...` alert generated from the `buttonClicked` method?  And are you expecting each to have a different message?  If not, can you clarify what you do expect to happen.

Comment: @flanker, in tableview i will get one textfield or sometimes three textfields depend on `paramName ` from json, if there is one textfield then i am able to validate but if there are three textfields then i am getting only last alertParam and alertMinL  for all three textfields, i am unable to validate if there are three textfields

Comment: So do you mean you'll get up to three cells in the tableView each with a textField called searchTextField?  And by validate, do you mean you want to run the code in `buttonClicked` against each of these tableview cells to check the value in their `searchTextField`?  Finally, where does the button sit - is it outside the tableView?

Comment: @flanker, yes you are right, button is outside the tableview

Answer (score 0):

To run the tests on all the cells you'll need to iterate through them.  If you are confident that they'll always be visible, then you could use the tableView's `visibleCells` property, but you'd be safer getting a reference to them through specific indexPaths.

Change you `buttonClicked` method to do the following...

First create the array of indexPaths you want to test.  This assumes they are all in section 0 and that you want to test every cell.  If not you will need to tweak this accordingly

```
let count = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
let indexPaths = (0..<count).map{IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}
```

The iterate through this array of indexPaths, retrieving the cell, and  running your validation code against it:

```
for indexPath in indexPaths {
 let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! YourTableCellType
 if cell.finalSearchValue.isEmpty{
    AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter \(self.alertParam ?? "")", in: self)
 } else if let textCount = textCount, let alertMinL = alertMinL, textCount < alertMinL {
    AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "\(self.alertParam ?? "") Not Less Than \(self.alertMinL ?? 0)", in: self)
 } else if let textCount = textCount, let alertMaxL = alertMaxL, textCount > alertMaxL {
    AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "\(self.alertParam ?? "") Not More Than \(self.alertMaxL ?? 0)", in: self)
 } else if self.finalSearchValueAmnt.isEmpty && hasFinalSearchValueAmnt{
    AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter Amount", in: self)
 } else{
    billerFetchService()
 }
}
```

Note: I've unwrapped your optional variable rather than nil coalescing them as I prefer it style-wise.

Comment: let count = here getting error `Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'`

Comment: you're using the wrong method.  It's `tableView.numberOfRows(inSection:)` not 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'